# HTML5 - vertical layout: flexible height + fill the rest

Tags: jquery, css, html, layout, flexbox

I have a dreaded height problem in html, IE9 and above, avoiding flex-box:

- I have header of one to three lines heigth (highly depends)
- the vertical rest of the page shall be filled a section. With scrollbars to that section, in case it's contents grow to long.

[image]

In simplied [stylus](http://stylus-lang.com/) syntax, [or as a full codepen](http://codepen.io/fnocke/pen/jBQjje?editors=1100):

```
html, body, header, section
  padding 0
  margin 0  
  font-size 40px
  box-sizing border-box

html
  background #f99
  height 100%

body
  background #9f9
  border 4px solid green
  height 100%

header
  border 4px solid darkred

section
  background #99f
  overflow auto
```

If the header height was known, life would be easy. I could easily resort to „corner pinning“:

```
  position absolute
  top 100px
  bottom 0
```

(Or have a fat top padding, and place the header above that, etc, etc...)

But sadly: its height varies. Any suggestions other than a [vertical flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)?

— looks like I need a corner pin with a little help from javascript regarding the top attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As IE9 support viewport units `vh`, you could do like this, without script, and an extra wrapper.

With this you get a dynamic header and a section that fills the remain viewport, and scroll when there is much content.

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/g8t9f6L8/)

Stack snippet

```css
html, body, .container {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  border: 4px solid green;
}
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
header {
  font-size: 40px;
  background: lightgray;
  border: 4px solid darkred; 
}
section {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; right: 0;
  top: 100%;
  height: calc(100vh - 100% - 8px);  /* the 8px (2 * 4px) is for the container's border */
  background: lightblue;
  font-size: 40px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <header>
      A fancy header
      <br> line two
    </header>
    <section>
      could be a lot of text
      <br> could be a lot of text
      <br> could be a lot of text
      <br> could be a lot of text
      <br> could be a lot of text
      <br> could be a lot of text
      <br> could be a lot of text
      <br> could be a lot of text
      <br> could be a lot of text
      <br> could be a lot of text
      <br> could be a lot of text
      <br> could be a lot of text
      <br> could be a lot of text
      <br> could be a lot of text
      <br> could be a lot of text
      <br> could be a lot of text
      <br> could be a lot of text
      <br> could be a lot of text
      <br> could be a lot of text
      <br> could be a lot of text
      <br> could be a lot of text
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, didn't know that I can use calc() „already“... — [but seems like it!](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc)

Comment: `-8px`, two times the border thickness ;)

Comment: @FrankNocke Of course ... :) ... my mistake, updated

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with JS, or in my example, jQuery:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZeVbBR

Get the heights of the window and the header and apply their difference as `min-height` to the section.